# MacBook Pro battery not charging error - long term fix

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power-management

I have a 2018 MacBook Pro 13 inch (the one without the touchbar). Over the past weeks, I have twice faced the situation where the charger is plugged in but the battery is draning and I get a "Battery not charging" message if I look at the Activity Monitor or hover over the battery icon.

Resetting the SMC seems to fix the problem but it reappears after a few days. Should I continue resetting the SMC each time or try something else? The laptop has a third party warranty but I cannot leave my home due to the COVID lockdown.

Comment: What version of macOS are you using and what percentage reading are you seeing where the battery isn't charging?

Comment: @Allan it's Catalina Version 10.15.5 (19F101). The battery charge is around 90-95% when it happens i.e. it seems to start charging again at 90% and stops at 95%

Comment: See the linked answer - especially the section on Catalina and Battery Health.  It will stop charging and actually reduce the max charge amount